# Core Data not persisting in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios5, nsmanagedobjectcontext

V. iOS 5

I have my Model2.xcdatamodelId containg 2 Entities. My Model is named 2, because I already have a Singleton named Model for some managing.

So from that, I have Model2.h and Model2.m.

**My Problem :** The first time, my Model2 is initialise, I put in some default data, then I commit. Works good, it says that my Model2 has been saved correctly. After what I am reading my data, data are shown from the database.. so it is successfuly in the database. **BUT.. when closing and killing my app**, my app seems to have lost all data.. and start over again with creating default data cause it is empty...

TIP: I'm thinking my problem could be about the initialize.. whithin those lines:

> ```
> NSArray * paths    = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
> NSString* basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
> NSURL   * storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"ProjectXYZ.db"]];
> ```

Since ProjectXYZ.db doesn't exist, it should create it?.. that's the part where I'm getting lost.. but it seems to worked on another project I've worked on... :S

Here's my Model2.h

> ```
> #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
> #import "Photos_Trophies.h"
> #import "Trophies.h"
> ```

```
@interface Model2 : NSObject


// High-level methods.
+ (void) commit;

...

 // Object Retrieval
 + (NSArray*) trophies;

 ...

 // Object Creation
 + (id) trophiesWithTitle:(NSString *)title;

 @end
```

And my Model2.m

> ```
> #import "Model2.h"
> #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
> ```

```
static NSManagedObjectContext * ctx;

@implementation Model2


+ (void) initialize {

    NSArray * paths    = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    NSURL   * storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"ProjectXYZ.db"]];
    NSError * error    = nil;

    ctx                            = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    ctx.persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil]];
    ctx.undoManager                = [[NSUndoManager alloc] init];

    if (![ctx.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSInMemoryStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }

    //TEMPORARY... these are default trophies for example
    if ([[Model2 trophies] count] == 0) {

        [self trophiesWithTitle:@"Saved Trophy Test 1"];
        [self trophiesWithTitle:@"Saved Trophy Test 2"];
        [self trophiesWithTitle:@"Saved Trophy Test 3"];

        [self commit];
    }
}

+ (void) commit {
    NSError* error = nil;

    if (![ctx save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"ERREUR DANS COMMIT: %@", error.localizedDescription);

        NSArray* detailedErrors = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSDetailedErrorsKey];
        if(detailedErrors && [detailedErrors count] > 0) {
            for(NSError* detailedError in detailedErrors) 
                NSLog(@"DetailedError: %@", [detailedError userInfo]);
        } else 
            NSLog(@"%@", [error userInfo]);
    } else
         NSLog(@"Model2 SAVED");
}

+ (NSArray*) trophies {
   NSFetchRequest* req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
   req.entity          = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Trophies" inManagedObjectContext:ctx];
   req.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"trophies_title" ascending:YES]];
   NSError* error      = nil;
   NSArray* objects    = [ctx executeFetchRequest:req error:&error];

  return objects;
}

+ (id) trophiesWithTitle:(NSString *)title {
    Trophies * trophies = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Trophies" inManagedObjectContext:ctx];
    trophies.trophies_title = title;

    return trophies;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is this: `NSInMemoryStoreType` You need to use a persistent backing store.

Do something like this:

```
NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self persistentStorePath]];

NSError *error = nil;
persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType 
                                              configuration:nil 
                                                        URL:storeUrl 
                                                    options:options 
                                                      error:&error]) {
    /*
     Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

     abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.

     Typical reasons for an error here include:
     * The persistent store is not accessible
     * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model
     Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
     */
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    NSAssert(error == nil, @"error creating persistentStoreCoordinator");   
}
```

Comment: What is the Type of persistentStorePath ?
Same for persistentStoreCoordinator... Seems like it miss something before those lines ?

Comment: Oh!.. I actually just changed the storetype for what you did, NSSQLiteStoreType with the code I add.. and it works number 1. Thx a lot for that tip. very appreciated